# Back button not showing up in view using navigation bar controller. (using storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift

Okay so I know this question has been asked multiple times but I can't find a solution so I am going to post here.

So basically I have a tab bar controller which is linked to multiple different views. In all of the views except for one the back button will not show up when I go to a new page. So my question is why the back button doesn't show up but the one that doesn't have a navigation controller does.

Here are some images and storyboard
[Navigation Problem](//imgur.com/a/Suo4E)

Comment: It is how iOS works. When you have more than 5 tabs, automatically creates a "More" tab and when you click it it loads a UITableView with a navigation controller, showing the navigation bar on top. If you run your app on a bigger device (iPad) you won't see the navigation bar

Comment: Okay that explains why one of them had it. Well how would I add a navigation controller to the tabs that are not a part of the more section?

Comment: Just embed each view controller into a navigation controler. 1. Select the first ViewController and go to Editor>Embed in>Navigation controller 2. Repeat the same with the other ViewControllers

Comment: Tried that but the back button doesn't show up. What I'm trying to do is have a view goes to another view and then the second view has the navigation controller. But when I do that the back button dosnt show up in the second view.